# ScrollView not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Im trying to create a application , which is just a simple list with text, buttons etc...

But the list is too large and it doesn't fit on a mobile screen.
So I tried to make a `ScrollView`, but it doesn't work.

EDIT: Scrolling doesn't work on the phone.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.blabla.tddddd.MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/feedback_send"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Aksjasjjs"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="KSADKDSK"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="salSKXAska"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="SKakas"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="sassa"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="jdasidjla"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hehehe"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hhehe"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="-----------------------------------"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="blabla"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you define, "doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Does it throw an exception? Does it display incorrectly? Also post the code where you are setting this xml as the content view.

Comment: The Problem is scrolling doesnt work on the phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the scrollbars. Try this:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/feedback_send"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```